# Crystal Reports is not showing values for database fields in text objects

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a text object and in it I dropped some fields from the database explorer and I put also some text in that text object. My problem is that the values for the database fields in the text objects are not shown. 
When I created the text object, I did it in the designer, and when previewed it worked.
When I export the report to a rpt file, those fields are not shown. My text object is in the report header.

I use Crystal reports 2008 and a database command for returning my records.

Please help !

Comment: Just so I'm clear: You are exporting this as a different Crystal Report (.rpt).  When you open the second Crystal Report, the value of the database field in the text object is not populated.  Is that the issue?  Do the other database fields in the new report populate?  Or is it just the database field in the text box that doesn't?

Comment: Yes, the value for the database field in the text object is not populated. The other fields in the report are populated.

Comment: If any of your field is null, wouldn't the entire text object be null as well? I think simplifying by not putting in a text box is sound troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I can't duplicate that behavior here.  The database field in the text box fills for me when I test it.  I'm curious, if you put the same database field in the Report Header outside of a text box, does it have a value when you export the report?  What if you move the text box down to the Page Header?  To the Detail block?  Do any of these things affect whether the database field fills or not?  If it never fills, it suggests that whatever conditions produce that value, i.e in the database, or at the report level via parameters, doesn't hold when you open the new .rpt.  Unfortunately, since a Crystal Report is such a visual medium, i.e. it's not just a block of code, I can't really "see" what the issues might be to be of much more help.

Comment: Well, in Crystal Reports, when I go on the preview tab, it works, but when I export my report it doesn't work. Before the exporting, I change some of the fields in the text object for translation, not the database fields, the fields defined by me that represents the code for translation. Do you think that this could be the problem? Also, when exporting the report, the database fields in the text object are like {table.fieldName} but in the designer when I create them have only {fieldName}.

Comment: Alex, try turning off your translation changes.  Do you still have these issues?  Also, what about Henry's suggestion to move these fields outside of the text boxes, do you still have issues then?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you move the field from the report-header section to the detail section?  it is possible that the first record in your result set is blank/null for that field.  if you move it (the textobject) to the details section, you can test my assertion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when translating the text objects something is lost. If I lose the translation, it works. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

why you use text object my friend?? you can use formula field exchange of text object and i am sure it can help you.
but if you use code to create your objects, you can use field object exchange of text object. you know text of text objects are constant,there for you cant add data base field in it